# Is it Thread-safe on this operating on ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Float, VoteItem> datum = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void vote(float graduation) {
    datum.putIfAbsent(graduation, new VoteItem(graduation, new AtomicInteger(0)));
    datum.get(graduation).getNum().incrementAndGet();
}
```

Does the method vote is totally thread safe? VoteItem.getNum() returns an AtomicInteger? Or if there is a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `VoteItem#getNum()` is thread-safe, e. g. returns final property, **and** no deletions are performed in parallel thread, your code is also thread-safe as there is no chance for `putIfAbsent()` to overwrite existing entry, and thus no chance for `get()` to return entry that is overwritten.

But there is more common way to achieve it using result of `putIfAbsent()`, which returns existing value if it is present for a given key:

```
public void vote(float graduation) {
    VoteItem i = datum.putIfAbsent(graduation, new VoteItem(graduation, new AtomicInteger(1)));
    if (i != null)
        i.getNum().incrementAndGet();
}
```

This handles possibility of concurrent removals as well. In contrast to your code, where concurrent removal can be performed between `putIfAbsent()` and  `get()` thus causing NPE, here no such situation can occur.

And consider to use [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead of `putIfAbsent()` in order to avoid unnessessary `VoteItem` creations:

```
public void vote(float graduation) {
    datum.computeIfAbsent(graduation, g -> new VoteItem(g, new AtomicInteger(0)))
         .getNum()
         .incrementAndGet();
}
```

Calling `getNum()` on result is possible because in contrast to `putIfAbsent()`, which returns null if value didn't exist prior to insertion, it returns just computed value.

Comment: Hi, Sasha, Can I ask one more question: If I do some following editing after VoteItem xyz = datum.get(xx);  on variable xyz, does it(xyz) thread-safe?

Comment: @YuSun it depends on if such edit is performed atomically or not (i. e. if there is a chance to other thread to see inconsistent state when edit is in progress, or perform concurrent edit breaking invariants). Hard to say without seeing the code

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.